# Can we use custom qbject-derived classes as types in javascript?

Tags: qt, qml

Let’s suposse I have a QObject-derived class:

```
Class Person : public QObject 
{
Q_OBJECT
Public:
QString _name;
Int _age;
}
```

Then at some place in my code I register this class into the context:
…setContextProperty("_Person",new Person(qApp));

Is there any way to use as _Person as type in a javascript expression? Something like like:

```
function f() {
var p = // function that returns a _Person
p._name = "John Smith"
}
```

I know we can use the object created by new Person() inside a component through “_Person”, but what if I want to access _name and _age in a javacript function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be defining _name and _age as [properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html).

There are examples [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qtwebkit-bridge.html#accessing-properties) and [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html#a-simple-example).

Note that the scriptable attribute will be required: -

> The SCRIPTABLE attribute indicates whether this property should be accessible by a scripting engine (default true). Instead of true or false, you can specify a boolean member function.

Comment: SCRIPTABLE is actually not needed for exporting properties to QML.

Comment: Is that because it defaults to true, so it is actually needed, but doesn't explicitly need specifying?

Comment: TBH I don't know what SCRIPTABLE is for, I just know it's not for QML.

Comment: The point of my question was how can we use an object of type Person  as type inside a javascript code.